# cascading combo boxes with bound form

Tags: ms-access

I am at my wits end here and have tried every code combination imaginable ( and what I can download) to get those elusive cascading combo boxes to work.
I have 6 of them and this is for a shipping database.
User has to select REGION then COUNTRY and then PORT.
That is both for origin and destination, so 6 in total.
I can get this to work only under the following conditions;
The Form is unbound, and have to use VBA/SQL to insert the selected values into the table.
Once the values are in the table, it is the ID's not the actual value (example "Asia").
I really need the form bound to the shipments table and combo boxes Control Source set to that particular Field.
I have a sinking feeling I am barking up the wrong tree and it cannot be done.
Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1):

`cmbRegions.RowSource = SELECT ID, Region FROM tblRegions`

`cmbCountry.RowSource = SELECT ID, Country FROM tblCountries WHERE RegionID = frmForm!cmbRegion`

`cmbPort.RowSource = SELECT ID, Port FROM tblPorts WHERE PortID = frmForm!cmbPort`

In the `AfterUpdate` event of `cmbRegions':

`cmbCountry.Requery`

In the `AfterUpdate` event of `cmbCountry':

`cmbPort.Requery`