# Can I Fix the a lookup field in Access database based upon a calculation or another field?

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, lookup

I am trying to create a database with field descriptions for a very large excel file that I have at work. I have created 3 tables- List of sheets, list of variables(including a lookup field pointing at the List of sheets table, so that I can select the sheet to which the variable belongs), and a third table which specify some validation rule.

In this third table, I want to see two lookup fields, one specifying the sheet in which the rule applies(say, 'Select Sheet'), and another specifying the variable(say, 'Select Variable'). I can point to the two different tables, but I want to do something a bit more nuanced than that. When I give a particular sheet name to 'Select Sheet', I want the lookup field for the variable('Select Variable') to show me only those variables which exists in that sheet.

I know that there probably will be solutions using forms, but this database is going to be very detailed and there are things to do afterwards, so I do not want to get into queries and forms before all data has been recorded in tables in a neat manner.

I have a good grasp of VBA in the context of excel and I am given to understand that I can extend the applications of Access using VBA. I am ready to do that, but I want to see before that whether this is some functionality of access that I am missing. Had anyone done anything similar before, and if so, did it take VBA to do it?

Comment: Advise not to build lookup fields in table. Build combobox or listbox on form. Also, what you want appears to be what is known as 'cascading' or 'dependent' combobox/listbox. Must be done with form and code. Common topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cascading combo boxes with bound form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561279/cascading-combo-boxes-with-bound-form)